# If or using else in PHP

Tags: php

I am just starting to learn a little about PHP; having trouble with the following code using IF || to check multiple statments from a form. here is my code; can someone give me some pointers?

```
  <html>
<body>
<?php
if (((($_POST['first_name']== null) || ($_POST['last_name']== null) || ($_POST['email']== null) || ($_POST['comments']== null)))) {
echo "Error one or more fields have been left empty please complete all details marked with a *.";}

else {

echo $_POST['first_name']; <br />
echo $_POST['last_name']; <br />
echo $_POST['email']; <br />
echo $_POST['telephone']; <br />
echo $_POST['comments']; <br />
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please describe the specific problem you are facing.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected on line 9

Comment: `else; {` should be `else {` (no semicolon)

Comment: Yeah i just noticed that and its giving the same problem

Comment: do not put a semicolon after else !!!!  ´else;´

Comment: Ok, thanks!  Please edit your question to include these *exact* error messages.

Comment: For crying out loud, use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), `isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['last_name'],...)` or more kittens will die!

Comment: Dear Friend, Whitespace is a good thing.  Please consider moving each or your ORed conditionals to a sepearate line so you can at a glance read what the logic is.  Also please consider using a 80 character max width (or less).  This will allow people to understand your code easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off with:

```
if( !$_POST['first_name']) echo "You left the First Name blank";
elseif( !$_POST['last_name']) echo "You left the Last Name blank";
elseif( !$_POST['email']) echo "You left the Email blank";
elseif( !$_POST['telephone']) echo "You left the Telephone blank";
elseif( !$_POST['comments']) echo "You left the Comments blank";
else {
    // do magic here.
}
```

You can customise the error messages, of course, and maybe do some stuff like highlight the boxes that were left empty to allow the user to see more clearly what they missed.

Comment: Just keeping it simple at at the moment, but thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1):

Use this format

```
<?php
if (((($_POST['first_name']== null) || ($_POST['last_name']== null) || ($_POST['email']==  null) || ($_POST['comments']== null)))) {
    echo "Error one or more fields have been left empty please complete all details marked with a *.";
}else{
    echo $_POST['first_name'], '<br />';
    echo $_POST['last_name'], '<br />';
    echo $_POST['email'], '<br />';
    echo $_POST['telephone'], '<br />';
    echo $_POST['comments'], '<br />';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't properly close the `<br>` tags. This below code should work.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
if (((($_POST['first_name']== null) || ($_POST['last_name']== null) || ($_POST['email']== null) || ($_POST['comments']== null)))) {
echo "Error one or more fields have been left empty please complete all details marked with a *.";}

else {

echo $_POST['first_name'];
echo "<br />";
echo $_POST['last_name'];
echo "<br />";
echo $_POST['email'];
echo "<br />";
echo $_POST['telephone'];
echo "<br />";
echo $_POST['comments'];
echo "<br />";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following semicolon is invalid:

```
else; {
    ^--- invalid
```

It terminates your `if()` statement, causing what should be the else clause to be its own independent code block.

Comment: I know I've just noticed that syntax error but I am having the exact same error.